# Searching for a Fantasy title - Book 1 of the Painter Trilogy?

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a good book ages ago and it had to do with some sort of color/painting magic and revolved around this boy's apprenticeship in the art.

I remember the author's name was female and the cover had a picture of the main character standing on a beach in front of a cliff with a rainbow over the sea.

I think it was something along *The lines of Colors in the Sand; Book 1 of The Painter Trilogy?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been able to find two series that seem to fit the bill.

The most obvious seems to be the first book in Sheila Gilluly's "[The Book of the Painter](http://www.goodreads.com/series/71462-the-book-of-the-painter)" Series; "[The Boy from the Burren"](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3251075-the-boy-from-burren)".

[image: The Boy from the Burren cover]

The main character is a young boy apprenticed to learn the magic of painting. The cover is a reasonable match to your description.

> *His future sold for a coin of gold, would he fulfill an ancient prophecy---or fall prey to the Wolf?*

Comment: This is definitely the book I was looking for. Thanks for the information! The cover was marginally different but the picture is the same - likely a different edition. I never thought I would figure it out...

Comment: @JonathanMcCarthy - *The best way to find yourself is to lose yourself in the service of others*...Enjoy your book and don't forget to keep asking questions :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably wrong, since the book is not a trilogy, but Melanie Rawn and a couple of other female authors had a book about a painter who could alter reality with paint. It was called *[The Golden Key](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/257333.The_Golden_Key)*. It's by a female author, but the cover of the novel does not resemble the description.

[image: Book cover]

> In a land where art is prized above all else, the master painters of the Grijalva family stand apart from other artists. Theirs is an art that can alter Reality, a secret Gift passed down for generations and always used for the good of the kingdom. But now the most talented of the Grijalvas has decided to use his power for his own dark intentions--with results more devastating than anyone could imagine!